# Gram matrix same quadratic form

Tags: linear-algebra

Let a Euclidean space of dimension be given 3. A system of 3 vectors of rank 2 was chosen in it. A Gram matrix was constructed on these vectors, and then multiplied by 2023. Consider the resulting matrix as a matrix of some quadratic form on another linear space over R in some fixed basis. At what maximum value of the parameter a matrix

$$ \left[\begin{matrix} с+2 & 3(с+2) & с+2 \\ 3(с+2) & 9(с+2) & 3(с+2) \\ с+2 & 3(с+2) & 3\end{matrix}\right]$$
is a matrix of the same quadratic form but in a different basis?

I understand definition of Gram matrix. But what do I have to do make sure it's a same quadratic form?
How to check that the transformed Gram matrix is ​​a matrix of the same shape but in a different basis? Thank you!
Please help. Thank you!

Comment: @Frog, hello. Sorry to bother but I have seen you answer in different question in linear algebra so can I ask your help?